# I cant get one of my pages to work on Heroku even though it works in my local environment

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, heroku

Basically I'm building this website right and everything is working except for one page called posts, when i render the page in my local host it works no problem but when the page is rendered in Heroku the page posts dosent render except for the nav bar. Every other commit to heroku is working with no issues at all. Every other page is working as well from my login to my home its just the pages only renders a blank white screen except for the nav bar which has no problems rendering.

This is where I believe the issue resides but i cant be sure

```
const displayPosts = posts.map(
    post => {
    return (
    <div onClick={() => {navigate(`/single`, {state: {id: post.id}})}} className="posts" key={post.id}> 
    <h1 id={post.id} className="postTitle"> {post.title} </h1>
    <img className="postImages" id='imagesPost' src={post.img_url} alt={post.title} />
    </div>

    )})

  return(
    <div id='postsPage'>
        <p>{displayPosts}</p>
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: visit console, you should have some clue i believe

Comment: thats kinda why im confused because I get no errors in my console and when I run it on localhost it works no problem

Comment: What, exactly, does "the page completely dosent render" mean? Please read [ask].

Comment: When I look at the posts page on my local host it renders with a background title for each post and an image for each post but after I pushed everything to heroku when I navigate to the posts page it only renders a blank white page not including my nav bar which it has no problems rendering, there is no background no posts no titles just a blank page. I believe it has something to do with my display posts constant and heroku just dosnent like it for some reason but i cant be sure. And sorry Chris im new to posting so im just trying to get the hang of it

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up needing to do was to migrate and seed my data in the heroku console
using rails db:migrate db:seed and then it worked